# How can I program various android powered phone buttons to launch my app?

Tags: android-intent, android-hardware

I have a requirement in my app where I have to select various buttons like **Search**, **Volume Up**, **Volume Down**, **Back buttons** to launch my app.

[image]

I know that I have to override the functionality of the these buttons but what API do I have to use and exactly how can I override them.

Answer (score 1):

Your application should be running and you need this code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ 
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) { 
       // Do your thing 
       return true;
   } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
}
```

List of keys: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: This is correct, you can not do this from outside the activity in use. Security reasons.